# How to extract feature vector for image when using CNN in Keras

Tags: keras, feature-extraction

I am doing a binary classification problem, my model architecture is as follow

```css
def CNN_model(height, width, depth):
    input_shape = (height, width, depth)

    model = Sequential()
    # Block 1
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, padding='VALID'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu', padding='VALID'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    # Block 2
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu', padding='VALID'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu', padding='VALID'))
    model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(19, 19)))

    # set of FC => RELU layers
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I need for each image on a test set, I get a 128-D feature vector collected from FC layer use for SVM classification. More detail, from `model.add(Dense(128))`. Can you please show me how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: One option: So you create the model, than  you compile the model and after that you just output the layer before the dense (J think the best is to get before Flatten layer because the Flatten will just get you a single vector with everything). You can try to see the FC pooling output as well, that will give you a lot of vectors based on your data. Second option: build a model up to Flatten layer, thank compile and use predict for each image to get for that picture the features (you may need to iterate thru all the images to get all the features).

Comment: model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(19, 19)))

    # set of FC => RELU layers
    model.add(Flatten()). #This part is where all the fratures vectors reside. If you test and work let me know please and will write as answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here the simplest way is to remove the **Dense** layer.

> I will answer with a counter example with similar layers but different input_shape:

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imsave
import  numpy  as  np
from keras.layers import *
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.applications import ResNet50
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras import backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(530, 700, 3), padding='VALID'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='VALID'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Block 2
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu', padding='VALID'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu', padding='VALID'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(19, 19)))

# set of FC => RELU layers
model.add(Flatten())

#getting the summary of the model (architecture)
model.summary()

img_path = '/home/sb0709/Desktop/dqn/DQN/data/data/2016_11_01-2017_11_01.png'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(530, 700))
img_data = image.img_to_array(img)
img_data = np.expand_dims(img_data, axis=0)
img_data = preprocess_input(img_data)

vgg_feature = model.predict(img_data)
#print the shape of the output (so from your architecture is clear will be (1, 128))
#print shape
print(vgg_feature.shape)

#print the numpy array output flatten layer
print(vgg_feature.shape)
```

> Here is the output model architecture with all layers:
>   [image: model summary]
>
> Also here is listed the feature vector: 
>   [image: feature vector size of (1,128) (numpy array)]
>
> Image used in the example:

[image: Image for the example]

Second method is for when using Functional Api instead of Sequencial() to use [How can I obtain the output of an intermediate layer?](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer)

```
from keras import backend as K
# with a Sequential model
get_6rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                  [model.layers[6].output])
layer_output = get_6rd_layer_output([x])[0]

#print shape
print(layer_output.shape)

#print the numpy array output flatten layer
print(layer_output.shape)
```

> One more useful step is the visualization of the features, I bet a lot of people want to see what see the computer and will illustrate only the "Flatten" layer output(better said the network):

```
def visualize_stock(img_data):
    plt.figure(1, figsize=(25, 25))
    stock = np.squeeze(img_data, axis=0)
    print(stock.shape)
    plt.imshow(stock)
```

**and the magic:**

```
visualize_stock(img_data)
```

[image: feature map]
Note: changed from input_shape=(530, 700, 3) from input_shape=(84, 84, 3) for better visualization for the public.

P.S: Decided to post so anyone who has this type of question to benefit (struggled with same type of questions recently).